# PhpStorm 11 EAP font blurred

Tags: phpstorm

Since I tried PhpStorm 11 EAP the font on my display is all blurred. Maybe this has to do with the change on the JDK? I am using Ubuntu 14.04. This hurts my eyes, do you know how I can fix this?

See this comparison

#### PhpStorm 10

[image]

*compared to*

#### PhpStorm 11

[image]

Comment: There is `Antialiasing` section at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance` -- try selecting different option. Other than that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-57233

Comment: I've tried different options under antialising - it does not help. Seems like it's not it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to switch back to Oracles Java JDK instead of using the bundled OpenJDK.

I did this by creating the file in the global settings directory of PhpStorm: `/home/MyUser/.PhpStorm2016.1/config/phpstorm.jdk` including the destination of my Java installation: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`